# Get data from another nodejs app to save it in another database

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

Suppose that a server built with nodejs and express and connected with mySQL Database. This app wants to get data from a MongoDB database and add edits to it.

For example, the server wants to get the users data from another `nodejs` app connected with `mongoDb` and add `voted` field  to each user, then save them to `mySQL` database.

What's the best design and approach for this situation ?

Comment: To connect and read from MongoDB using NodeJS driver you have to write code. Here are examples: [MongoDB NodeJS Tutorials](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/main/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Simple "Stupid" solution (with coupling between services):

- create REST endpoint at the application (A) which returns the necessary data, and from
  your app (B) call this endpoint directly (http call) (fetch BaseURL from your configs
  or route if you're using API Gateway), add the votes into your domain(business layer in app B)
  and save to the MySql DB.

2- a little bit complex one ( which guarantee no coupling between services)

- is to use a message broker like "RabbitMQ", and depend on the "Pub/Sub" model, where
  you publish a message to the broker (when app A add a new User to MongoDB), then you
  subscribe to this from your app B, to fetch the message (this message will include
  the data you want "the user object" mutate it, then save to Mysql )

---

- this simple answer, supposed no data synchronization between the two databases, as you're going to mutate the "User" in one of them, otherwise, if you want synchronization, you need to fire an event after mutation done, and the service A will subscribe to this fetches the message, update its MongoDB